# How to use dependency injection to apply a class static method?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

I'm building a custom form (extending ConfigFormBase) and using static method File::load($fid). How to use dependency injection to call this method?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **__construct()** you can implement like this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
}
```

and **create()** method

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
    );
}
```

You can use this service to get the file storage:

```
$file_storage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file');
```

and then load the file:

```
$file = $file_storage->load($fid);
```

Comment: I have already checked for that possibility but in vain. entityTypeManager() is not present from ConfigFormBase calss.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: This is only one half of it - you also need to override the ‘create` method and instantiate an appropriate instance in it. That’s how the dependency gets injected

Comment: I added in my class declaration: 
    class myClassForm extends ConfigFormBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface

Comment: @fromTheFifties you don't need implements ContainerInjectionInterface because ConfigFormBase extend FormBase and FormBase already implement ContainerInjectionInterface.

Comment: in the __construct(...) I have this warning 'Missing parent constructor call'

Comment: Yes you need to construct the parent with its required parameters as well, that's just how OOP works. It sounds like you haven't read https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8 yet, it's important that you read an understand that before ploughing ahead with development

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code implementation as I was having this sort of warning:

> Expected \Drupal\file\FileStorageInterface, got object Invocation
>   parameter types are not compatible with declared.

So I updated create method to get the file storage directly:

```
class MyClassForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * File storage for files.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\file\FileStorageInterface
   */
  protected $fileStorage;

  /**
   * SiteSettingsForm constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\file\FileStorageInterface $file_storage
   *   File storage for files.
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
    parent::__construct($config_factory);
    $this->fileStorage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('file');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use the `entity_type.manager` service and then in your `__construct` assign `$file_storage` with `->getStorage('file')`

Comment: Well the best would be to inject the FileStorage in the first place.
Unfortunaley standard D8 does not come up with a Storage ServiecProvider functionality. 
Because right now no matter you assign the FileStorage in the constructor, in your test you will have to still mock the "getStorage" method no matter what.